# How to include externel user files into UWP side-loading package?

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3, winui

Say I use some .json files to descript some object data which effect to the program's behavior, I hope to use these files in the following scenarios

1. The default values, for this purpose, I need a set of files follows with the application to be packed and installed.
2. I wish it could be edited by human manually. (Because something have no interface to be modify on UI)

Both user and the program need to kwnow the location the files will be placed after installation.

In debugging stage, I could put these files in the user\AppData\Local.. folder and I know how to access them, but I don't know how to put files into the package and will them generated to anywhere after install?

Thank you for any suggestion.

ps.

- I use the **"Blank App (WinUI 3 in UWP)"** template to create my
  application.
- I'm new in UWP and WinUI, I used to write traditional Windows Form programs.

Comment: Yes it works. I didn't know until today that an UWP App runs like in a container which isolated from the original file system. The files we can access is in the installation folder and the local folder. That's a bit like an Android App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to include externel user files into UWP side-loading package?

You could place the json file into app's project and set the file property as `Content`, then it will deploy into [installtion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation?view=winrt-22000) folder after package install. and please note the json file is readonly in the installtion folder.
so you could call CopyAsync method copy the file to the destination folder that app's [local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#access-application-data-locations) folder with full permission.

For more details about file [access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) please refer this document.